# Storing variables from a For loop into an array

Tags: powershell

The code I have currently searches through serveral files to look for a specific server name in the file. It also outputs whether it found the server to a text file with either pass or fail. The code below shows this, but it writes to the file on each loop, so if it is in the 3rd file it will write "fail fail pass".

```
$Server = "ServerName"
For ($AddDays = -2; $AddDays -lt 1; $AddDays++){
    $DatePrev = (Get-Date).AddDays($AddDays).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd')
    write-host $DatePrev 
    $FilePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\SaScripts\$DatePrev.tsv"
    if([bool]((import-csv $FilePath -Delimiter "`t") -match $Server)) {
        "Pass" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\Desktop\SaScripts\$Server.txt" -Append -NoNewline
        }
        else{
        "Fail" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\Desktop\SaScripts\$Server.txt" -Append -NoNewline
        } 
}
```

The code above will output the below, if say the server name is in the 3rd file:

`fail fail pass`

I need it to only write to the text file either a Pass or a Fail once, so if it found server name in any of the files or if it didn't. The only way I can think about doing it is storing the results from each loop into an array and then seeing if there was a Pass for any of the values.

Any help would be much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You can initially presume that server is not found (variable `$Found`). If you find it, just update the variable to `$true`. And at the end, just display once the result based on that variable.

```
$Server = "ServerName"
$Found = $false
For ($AddDays = -2; $AddDays -lt 1; $AddDays++){
    $DatePrev = (Get-Date).AddDays($AddDays).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd')
    write-host $DatePrev 
    $FilePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\SaScripts\$DatePrev.tsv"
    if([bool]((import-csv $FilePath -Delimiter "`t") -match $Server)) {
        $Found = $true
    }
}
if ($Found) {
    "Pass" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\Desktop\SaScripts\$Server.txt" -Append -NoNewline
} else {
    "Fail" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\Desktop\SaScripts\$Server.txt" -Append -NoNewline
}
```

Comment: P.S. If the speed is critical, you can also exit the for loop after server is found. But, I would leave to you to find out how to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to know if the servername can be found anywhere in the file, there should be no need to use Import-Csv (unless you are planning to search on one particular data column in there..)

Because of that, you could make use on the [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet and a simple counter like this:

```
$Server = "ServerName"
$found  = 0

for ($AddDays = -2; $AddDays -lt 1; $AddDays++){
    $DatePrev = (Get-Date).AddDays($AddDays).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd')
    write-host $DatePrev 
    $FilePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\SaScripts\$DatePrev.tsv"
    if (Test-Path -Path $FilePath -PathType Leaf) {
        # switch '-List' returns only the first instance of matching text to make it more efficient
        if (Select-String -Path $FilePath -Pattern $Server -SimpleMatch -Quiet -List) {
                $found++  # increment the counter
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "File '$FilePath' not found.."
    }
}

$msg = if ($found -gt 0) { "Pass" } else { "Fail" }
$msg | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\Desktop\SaScripts\$Server.txt" -Append -NoNewline
```